# Why do the @see and @linkplain JavaDoc commands throw "Can't find"-warnings when referencing to a method?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I am currently generating JavaDoc for a project that I did for a class in university. I am using dozens of @see and @link/@linkplain references to refer to classes and methods from everywhere within the project. So far, all those references work just fine. There are however two warnings that I can't get rid off and I have no idea as to what I am doing wrong. I have double checked that the spelling of the methods is correct (via ctrl -> space).

I get the following warnings (I have kept the original package, class and method names because I am sure that the JavaDoc Syntax is correct).

*"... warning - Tag @see: can't find setRobotStatus(RobotStatuses) in communication.ComManager*"
*"... warning - Tag @linkplain: can't find decodeMessage(SourceDestinationIdentifier, String) in communication.MessageDeEncoder"*

The corresponding JavaDoc lines look like this:

```
@see communication.ComManager#setRobotStatus(RobotStatuses)
```

and

```
{@linkplain communication.MessageDeEncoder#decodeMessage(SourceDestinationIdentifier, String) decodeMessage}
```

The @see tag is located with the JavaDoc comment for a method within an Interface. The @linkplain tag is located in the JavaDoc comment for the MessageDeEncoder class. I have looked at the following questions on StackOverFlow but couldn't find an answer that would solve my problem:

[Javadoc link to method in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496038/javadoc-link-to-method-in-other-class)

[JavaDoc @see for MyClass constructor returning a warning "reference not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970823/javadoc-see-for-myclass-constructor-returning-a-warning-reference-not-found)

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the package name, class name and method declarations? Which Eclipse / Java version are you on?

Comment: @icyrock.com: I am using Eclispe Mars.2. I have JDK1.8 installed, the project itself has a compliance level of 1.7.  Requested information for the @see-tag: Method declaration: `public void setRobotStatus(RobotStatuses newStatus)` contained in the class `ComManager` contained in the package `communication`. @linkplain-tag: Method declaration: `public void decodeMessage(SourceDestinationIdentifier source, String message)` contained in the class `MessageDeEncoder` contained in the package `communication`.

Comment: Thanks, it would be better to update the post though, much easier to read. Are you able to reproduce this by creating a new project and copying only the necessary classes? Does the result change if you rename the package, classes and / or methods? Does it work for other methods in the same classes?

Comment: @icyrock.com I will be going on holiday tomorrow. I will give your ideas a try when I am back.